# Can't fix an error caused by cheerio while using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to fetch titles of different posts from a [webpage](https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/) using `axios` and `cheerio` but the script always throws this error `Error: cheerio.load() expects a string`. How can I fix it?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const startLink = 'https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/';

const getPostTitles = (link) =>{
        const resp = axios.get(link);
        const $ = cheerio.load(resp.data);
        const postTitles = [];

        $('div > p.title > a').each((_idx, el) => {
            const postTitle = $(el).text()
            postTitles.push(postTitle)
        });

        return postTitles;
};

const results = getPostTitles(startLink);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Axios.get()` returns a promise, so you need to either `await` it , or use .then() to get the result. I've used the `async/await` syntax below, this will display the post titles:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const startLink = 'https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/';

const getPostTitles = async (link) => {
    const resp = await axios.get(link);
    const $ = cheerio.load(resp.data);
    const postTitles = [];

    $('div > p.title > a').each((_idx, el) => {
        const postTitle = $(el).text()
        postTitles.push(postTitle)
    });

    return postTitles;
};

async function testGetPostTitles() {
    const results = await getPostTitles(startLink);
    console.log(results);
}

testGetPostTitles();
```

Comment: Ta.. some interesting stuff in that thread!